# Mostrar value num input do type datetime-local

Tags: php, html

Tenho este código:

```
$tabela5 .= '<td> <input type="datetime-local" name= "DataInicio" id= "DataInicio" value="'. date("Y-m-d H:i:s") .'"></td>';
```

Mas o input não mostra a data e a hora atual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque por isso:

```
date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s")
```

No HTML deve ter um `T` entre a data e hora. O `\` é para escapa-lo